# The maximum an complex expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If Z is a complex number such that :
$|Z+4|\leq3$ , find the maximum value of $|Z+1|$

My turn:

$|(x+4) + yi|\leq 3$

represents the surface of acircle whose center is (-4 ,0) and its radius is 3 , then

$-7\leq x \leq -1$ , then

$-6 \leq (x+1)\leq 0$

Then
$0\leq(x+1)^2 \leq 36 $

And

$-3\leq y \leq 3$

Then

$0\leq y^2 \leq 9$

Then

$0\leq (x+1)^2 + y^2 \leq 45$

Then

$|Z +1|\leq 3\sqrt{5}$

Then the required maximum value is $3\sqrt{5}$

Is the solution correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As seen from the graph, the maximum $|z+1|$ is at $z=-7$, i.e.

$$|z+1| \le |-7+1| = 6$$

which can also be shown analytically as follows,

$$|z+1|=|z+4+(-3)| \le |z+4| + |-3| \le 3 +3 = 6$$

Answer (score 3):

The upper bound you proved is correct in the sense that it's true, but it's not attained so ultimately incorrect. As you said, the region $|Z+4| \leq 3$ is a disc of radius $3$ and center $(-4, 0)$. Finding the maximum of $|Z+1|$ asks 'how far is the furthest point in the aforementioned disk from the point $(-1, 0)$'. If you draw a picture you'll be able to see that the point that achieves the maximum is $(-7, 0)$ making the desired upper bound
\begin{equation}
|Z+1| \leq 6
\end{equation}

Comment: I think there is another segment between (-1,0) and a point in the disc such that it length is more than 6 . Why we ignore it ?@pg-star

Comment: There won't be any line segment, since in a circle the point which is the farthest distance from (-1,0) is the point which is diametrically opposite to it, which is (-7,0) as argued by @pg_star. Thus the maximum distance is precisely the diameter of the circle, $6$.